# How to create nested components?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a component that has a few components nested inside of it with props.

Something like that:

```
<DivWithBlueBackground>
  <Title />
  <Sometext theColor="white">This text is white</Sometext>
</DivWithBlueBackground>
```

How can I write Sometext component?
Tried that but not sure where to define props for Sometext:

```
const DivWithBlueBackground = ( {children} ) => ( <div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}> {children} </div> );
const Title = () => <div>The title </div> ;
const Sometext = ( props, {children} ) => <div style={{ color: props.theColor }}> {children} </div>
```

Comment: You may name DivWithBlueBackGround as D, TitleText  as T, JustSomeText as JST so you end up with <D><T /><JST /><JST /></D>

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial I didn't find the way to do the {children} thing. How can I just create a component that has blue background and I can put anything inside so everything will have blue background inside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sending `props` to a `component` is just like what you already did or have:-

```
<DivWithBlueBackground>
  <Title />
  <Sometext 
    theColor="white" 
    otherProp="otherProp"
  >
    This text is white
  </Sometext>
</DivWithBlueBackground>
```

1. You can receive `props` as `props` or whatever `args` you wanna put:-

```
const Sometext = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ color: props.theColor }}>Some content...</div>
  )
}
```

2. Or you could do `props` `destructuring`:-

```
const Sometext = ({ theColor, otherProp }) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ color: theColor }}>Some content of {otherProp}</div>
  )
}
```

Any of above methods will work.

Comment: Your props destructuring example has solved my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

following comment.

```
const DivWithBlueBackGround = ({children}) => {
     return (<div>{children}</div>)
}
```

Child Component

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {

  return ( <div style={{ backgroundColor: props.theColor }}></div>

}
```

Passing props to children.

```
const App = () => {

return (<DivWithBlueBackGround>
           <ChildComponent theColor="blue" />
           <ChildComponent theColor="red" />
        </DivWithBlueBackGround>)
}
```

you can name it theColor or anything you want, and they will be accessible by **props** in ChildComponent

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think I wasn't clear in my question because I got confused between 'children' and 'props' I edited it and added "theColor" props to the children of the DivWithBlueBackground. How to define that?

Comment: I have updated the answer, is that what you want? Passing props to children.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you should use string interpolation to define props explicitly.

```
const DivWithBlueBackground = ( {children} ) => (<div style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue' }}> {children} </div> );
const Title = () => <div>The title </div> ;
const Sometext = ( props, {children} ) => <div style={{ color: `${props.theColor}` }}> {children} </div>
```

Comment: the text inside Sometext doesn't show up somehow. Is there any reason why? I don't get any errors. <Sometext theColor="white">White text </Sometext>